How can I properly update react-native android gradle to work with react native 0.71.4
I woke up to see that my react native application would no longer compile on android properly?
It keeps complaining about it's gradle and skd version. I have tried upgrading but get a completely different error.
My configuaration:
"react-native": "0.71.4",
build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-`projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext {
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
}
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
}
}

gradle wrapper properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dist


This is the message i'm getting right now
BUILD FAILED in 56s
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
2 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:


Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0' requires libraries and applications that
depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
Android APIs.
:app is currently compiled against android-33.

Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle plugin 7.3.1 is 33.
Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
compileSdkVerion of at least 34.
Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
on).
2.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0' requires libraries and applications that
depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
Android APIs.
:app is currently compiled against android-33.
Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle plugin 7.3.1 is 33.
Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
compileSdkVerion of at least 34.
Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installedon).
if i upgrade to any other version of gradle (8.0, 8.0.1, 8.1), it complains about kotlin version:
**'kotlin.collections.ArraysKt ___ ArraysKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0** 
Please a great help would be appreciated, i'm suppose to be submiting this app to client, but this has been messing me up for days, and i'm at my wits end.

native 0.74.1, this is my build.gradle, maybe this works to you:
  buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        appCompatVersion = "1.4.2"
        googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "21.0.1"
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1')
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

What version of Gradle?  Are you using v8?
